# MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluste not ip address

Tags: reactjs, node.js, database, mongodb

my backend looks like this

```
 import mongoose from "mongoose";
    
  const connectDB = (url) =>{
    mongoose.set('strictQuery',true);
        
     mongoose.connect(url)
        .then(()=>console.log("MongoDb conected"))
            .catch((err)=>console.log(err));
        }

export default connectDB;
```

and the error looks like this

```
server has started on port http://localhost:8080
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Users\Bikram ghoshal\Desktop\ImageGenerate\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:875:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\Bikram ghoshal\Desktop\ImageGenerate\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:826:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-7mtdcur-shard-00-00.fueb0lk.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-7mtdcur-shard-00-01.fueb0lk.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-7mtdcur-shard-00-02.fueb0lk.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-vz8z2y-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

After connecting to the database, I encountered an error that appeared without any changes to the code. Despite updating the network access IP address to 0.0.0.0, the issue persists. I seek assistance in resolving this matter. Any guidance or support would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `[ServerDescription]` part should have the error encountered when attempting to connect to each node.